# create the pixel size for Dicom_Picture in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, pixel, medical-imaging

I have pictures in .dcm format. From Dicominfo I learned that the pixel spacing is [0.9,0.9] mm and the slice thickness is 1.98 mm.

My task: I should get the picture size in real (world) coordinates and then display the pictures in all three projections in matlab.

I had an idea that I would create a matrix in matlab, but it is difficult for me to create the pixel size spacing.
I mean that the pixel in the matrix is like a square and is 0.9mm * 0.9mm.
I don't know if my approach is correct and if there is an easy way to solve the problem.
Thank you very much for every answer

Answer (score 1):

several plotting functions allow you to specify x/y/z positions of each pixel/voxel, including `imagesc`, `pcolor`, here is an example using imagesc.

```
% vol stores your dicom volume
vol=rand(40,50,30);
dx=[0.9,0.9,1.98];
imagesc((0:size(vol,1)-1)*dx(1), (0:size(vol,2)-1)*dx(2), vol(:,:,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Could it be with imshow the picture displayed without imagesc?

Comment: `imshow` does not directly accept x/y positions, but you can set the `xdata` and `ydata` properties of the plotted object, like this: `ss=imshow(vol(:,:,1));; set(ss,'xdata',(0:size(vol,1)-1)*dx(1), 'ydata',(0:size(vol,2)-1)*dx(2));`

Comment: I generally avoid using imshow because it requires the image processing toolbox; in comparison, `imagesc` is supported in matlab core, so everyone has matlab has it.

Comment: Yes, it worked with imshow, but I also used zdata with imshow, but it didn't work.
Isn't zdata defended at imshow?